# Where is the temporary file generated by chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

A chrome extension generated a image file, then opened in a chrome tab, the url of that tab is

```
filesystem:chrome-extension://fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl/temporary/screencapture-www-google-com-webhp-1436884653249.png
```

Is it possible to locate the temporary file in the OS?

FYI. here is the code that generate the file

```
 window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, size, function(fs){
    fs.root.getFile(name, {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.onwriteend = onwriteend;
            fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
}, errorHandler);
```

The chrome extension is installed on my win7 PC at:

```
C:\Users\{myName}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Extensions\fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl\0.0.15_0
```

but cannot find any temporary file/folder.

Comment: this is not really a programming question.

Comment: Indeed, it's not. FWIW the answer is to use the `procmon` or similar utility.

Comment: look at the html5 filesystem viewer extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows OS ,please follow below steps:

1-go to C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System

2-Sort the folders according to date modified. find the correct folder and open it.

3-Go further down through that folder (1  or 2 steps).There you will find your captured files without any extension (there may be File written on Type bar).Change their extensions to *.png (or another picture format you want)

4-Enjoy

Comment: I can go to C:\Users*username*\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data, but no further. seems I don't have "Default" folder.

Comment: @Sam558 "Default" is the profile name (by _default_), so for you it will be "Profile 1" judging from your question.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, the location is based on the active user's `Library` folder (as of Chrome 56 anyway). Here's an example:

`/Users/tester1/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System/027/t/00`

Where `00` is a file that contained the JSON blob I had previously stored with the webkitRequestFileSystem API.

@nemenem has the right approach for penetrating Chrome's obfuscation:

1. Open `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System/`
2. Sort by date in descending order
3. Navigate down the folder structure to find the data that you've written out.